# DHT22 need pull down/up ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, temperature-sensor

I have the strange pb.
My esp8266 was working fine with my DHT22 and then failed every time.
I loaded an example sketch in a other ESP8266 and I have the same pb.... until I shut down -> up the DHT22 when the ESP8266 is working.
To check more, I added this at the setup before `dht.begin()` :

```
      digitalWrite(0, LOW); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000); // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
```

And it works. But I don't know why I need to do this "pull up".
PS : I already tried with or without the 10K resistor, same pb.
PS2 : I already tried with 3.3v or 5V for DHT22. Same pb.

Any idea ?

Comment: how is the DHT22 wired and what esp8266 module you use?

Comment: I use a nodeMCU (Bangood, Geekcreit). The DHT22 is wired like this : https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-io-basics-temperature-and-humidity/arduino-wiring?fbclid=IwAR0cLuSXA4HMeCTtD-YC03FJ9pqGUj37HY_hyMXhz5dp4z-I-HkIzA1Or0Y

Comment: to which pin of NodeMcu is the DHT data pin 2 connected? to D2 (io 0)?

Comment: I connected it to pin D4. But the pb is I can see the data AFTER the pullUp trick. So why ?

Comment: sorry D2 is not io 0, it is io 4

Comment: Can you use a i2c humidity and temperature sensor? The dht sensors are not accurate and they cause many problems. The esp8266 is sensitive for this bug: https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/issues/48 The data signal has a shortcut since that library was written. The issue is from 2015 and adafruit has not fixed it yet, so they probably never will. Please use a i2c humidity and temperature sensor.

Comment: No, I haven't an other one. As the DHT11 and 22 seams to be used frequently, I thought it was good. I will check the issue. Does it work if we modify the lib code ?

Comment: Cocorico, when you use @Jot in your answer, I will get notified. There are also timing issues with the esp8266 and the dht11 / dht22 sensors, and library incompatibilities. That was already a problem, but since this year many have issues. So please use a i2c humidity and temperature sensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question in case someone has the same issue.
**The ADAFRUIT_DHT lib DOESN'T WORK WITH ESP8266.** It keep saying `Failed to read from DHT sensor!` until you unplug/plug the VCC on the DHT.

But the **DHTesp** ([link](https://github.com/beegee-tokyo/DHTesp)) works very well at first try !

Thx @Juraj and @Jot for their support.